# Symfony Form - Collection Type with Checkboxes inside

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I am using Symfony 5, I want to have a "User Edit" page in administration, in which I will change User Roles, I want to have checkboxes to define which role assign to user, so for that, I need Collection Type with CheckboxType entry inside (if I am true), but for first I can't use user roles array as value for collection type

```
$builder
        ->add('roles', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => CheckboxType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'required' => false,
            ],
        ])
```

This throws error

> **Unable to transform value for property path "[0]": Expected a Boolean.**

after that, I tried to use a model transformer to change the value, below is code how I did that

```
$builder->get('roles')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function($rolesAsArray){
                $rolesAsArray = array_flip($rolesAsArray);
                foreach($rolesAsArray as &$role){
                    $role = true; // I also tried to set key instead of value - true
                }
                return $rolesAsArray;
            },
            function($rolesAsString){
                dump($rolesAsString);die;
            }
        ));
```

After this, I didn't get an error but I get the form with this look

[image: screenshot of error]

So I haven't any option to change labels, and even I am submitting a form with these fields it throws an error

> **Expected argument of type "array", "null" given at property path "roles".**

I found a way to do this with [Select Box](https://dthlabs.com/select-or-checkbox-in-a-symfony5-form-for-user-roles/), but I can't found any way to do it with Checkbox.

If you have any ideas tell me, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ChoiceType :

```
$builder->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'form.label.role',

                'choices' => User::ROLES,
                'choice_translation_domain' => 'user',
                'multiple'  => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
                ));
```

In User entity:

```
const ROLES = array(
    'roles.admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
    'roles.secretary' => 'ROLE_SECRETARY',
    'roles.user' => 'ROLE_USER'
);
```

Comment: no, I need to have multiple roles, with the select box I already did, It's not so hard, the question is to have this functionality with checkboxes

Comment: You have multiple roles with checkbox when you use ChoiceType  with multiple=true and expanded=true, i use it for my user roles